# MySQL Connector/NET check for new changes in table

Tags: .net, mysql, mysql-connector, socks

I'm using MySQL Connector/NET and I want to check if there's any changes in a table, normally I have use a timer and every time it ticks, it will check for new changes.

But a timer is not a good solution. everytime my software has to run a SELECT command, that wastes a lot of time and resources. I want to use an Event instead of a timer that checks for new changes.

Someone told me u have to use SOCKS or something. Anyone has any idea?

Answer (score 2):

As aleroot pointed out, if you were using MSSQL then SqlDependency is exactly the answer that you are looking for. But as you are using MySQL, we don't have much options available.

A concept known as WebSockets was introduced in HTML 5. It is a type of PUSH technology. Although I am not sure of whether it can be used in your scenario, please go through the article available at: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today/

The remaining option is to poll the database periodically for any change in data. Please find below some suggestions to reduce the load on the server while still making use of polling:

1) If the data in not being inserted periodically, you can use a query to check for the row count (instead of retrieving the entire data) and retrieve the data only if there is a change in the current and previous counts.

2) You can make use of a separate table which will be updated using a trigger whenever there is a change in the data. Your application can periodically query the new table to identify whether any data was changed in the parent table.

Try to improvise a solution and do share it.